# pm2 stopped running my program. Why and when?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, process, pm2

I had a node process running with pm2. It showed up in the result of `pm2 list`. Now I see the process isn't running anymore, and `pm2 list` is empty.

Are there any pm2 logs which show me when and why it stopped running my node process?

Answer (score 2):

Well first of all you have the `pm2 logs` command that will show you logs, but pm2 is running by the user that ran the `pm2 start` commant. Meanning that if you were in sudo mode and ran `pm2 start` you will not see the application list from a regular user.

If this is not the issue, you should know that if you restart your machine, the list deletes. if you want to keep the list after restart, you need to run `pm2 save` after you finish starting your applications/json configuration file.

Comment: I tried to use `ppm2 save` after starting the process. It responds with two lines, saying `Successfully saved in /root/.pm2/dump.pm2`. But when I reboot using `sudo reboot` and after reboot look at the list using `pm2 list` it doesn't show the process. I'm always logged in and doing everything as root. Any idea what could go wrong here?

Comment: Did you do the ` pm2 save ` with the same user you loaded the applications into pm2 using `pm2 start`? Try doing all pm2 actions on sudo mode and see if they are being saved

Comment: BTW, before all you need to do `pm2 startup` in order for pm2 to start automatically.
So you will need to do all the pm2 related actions from the same user (I recommend doing all pm2 actions with sudo before)